# Protobuf getAllFields() performance

Tags: java, performance, protocol-buffers

We are using protobuf as our messaging, and each message, we loop thru the set fields, and do something with it.

We loop it using

```
    for ( final Map.Entry<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> entry : msg.getAllFields().entrySet()) {
            FieldDescriptor field = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
```

Under profiler, we found that this GetAllFields uses most of the time, and I did some research, and it looks like there is no other way.

I know that we can use do something like this:

```
    for ( final FieldDescriptor field : msg.getDescriptorForType().getFields()) {
        if (!msg.hasField(field)){
            continue;
        }
        Object value = message.getField(field);
```

But getDescriptorForType returns all the fields rather than just the set ones.

Does anyone know of another better performing way to loop thru the fields?  I believe the problem with getAllFields are creating a new map each time, and also reflection.  Can i force it to use Trove map inside rather than a regular hashmap?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

`getAllFields()` is part of Protobuf's reflection interface (not to be confused with Java's reflection). Protobuf reflection is, alas, quite slow -- it's essentially like using an interpreted language rather than a compiled one.

If you need your code to be fast, the way to do it is to call the generated-code methods directly. Unfortunately this can be tedious if you're doing something repetitive to every field. One thing you might consider is writing a code generator plugin for `protoc` to auto-generate the repetitive code (much like `protoc` generates code for the protobuf classes themselves). For more on how to do that, see [the docs on descriptor.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin.pb).

Comment: From the 2 ways of looping. Which one is more performant? And for that link, any equivalent to java version?

Comment: @Ted getAllFields() internally essentially loops over all fields checking if each is present, so doing that yourself is probably faster. OTOH if you use extensions then looping over the descriptor fields won't tell you everything. Regarding the descriptor.proto link, it's a protobuf; you can use it in any language.